# Creating and sending data packets in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Let's say I want to send the following data to a socket using C or C++, all in one packet:

```
Headers
-------
Field 1: 2 byte hex
Field 2: 2 byte hex
Field 3: 4 byte hex

Data
----
Field1 : 2 byte hex
Field1 : 8 byte hex
```

What would the code typically look like to create and send the packet containing all this data?

Comment: Related external link: http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/

Comment: If C++ I suggest looking at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html) for an excellent cross platform networking library.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "all in one packet"? Do you mean the link-layer packets (Ethernet, PPP, etc.)? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Rob, well, I would like to not call send() multiple times to send the headers and the data. I would like to send the headers and data together using one single call to send(). Unless this is not how it's normally done?

Comment: That's a fine requirement, @Chad. It's just that "packet" means different things in different contexts, and I wanted to make sure you weren't talking about something else. I've seen programs send the headers and data in one `send`, 2 `send`s, and in more than 2 `send`s. There is no "normal" there, just whatever is convenient to the organization in your code.

Comment: Don't forget that TCP/IP is stream oriented, not message oriented. A given `send` can make the message be recieved by several `recv`. So both ends should buffer the connection

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's suppose that your program is already organized to have the header in one `struct` and the data in another `struct`. For example, you might have these data structures:

```
#include <stdint.h>
struct header {
    uint16_t f1;
    uint16_t f2;
    uint32_t f3;
};
struct data {
    uint16_t pf1;
    uint64_t pf2;
};
```

Let's call this organization "host format". It really doesn't matter to me what the host format is, as long as it is useful to the rest of your program. Let's call the format that you will pass to the `send()` call "network format". (I chose these names to match the [`htons`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) (host-to-network-short) and [`htonl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) (host-to-network-long) names.)

Here are some conversion functions that we might find handy. Each of these converts your host format structures to a network format buffer.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
void htonHeader(struct header h, char buffer[8]) {
    uint16_t u16;
    uint32_t u32;
    u16 = htons(h.f1);
    memcpy(buffer+0, &u16, 2);
    u16 = htons(h.f2);
    memcpy(buffer+2, &u16, 2);
    u32 = htonl(h.f3);
    memcpy(buffer+4, &u32, 4);
}
void htonData(struct data d, char buffer[10]) {
    uint16_t u16;
    uint32_t u32;
    u16 = htons(d.pf1);
    memcpy(buffer+0, &u16, 2);
    u32 = htonl(d.pf2>>32);
    memcpy(buffer+2, &u32, 4);
    u32 = htonl(d.pf2);
    memcpy(buffer+6, u32, 4);
}
void htonHeaderData(struct header h, struct data d, char buffer[18]) {
    htonHeader(h, buffer+0);
    htonData(d, buffer+8);
}
```

To send your data, do this:

```
...
char buffer[18];
htonHeaderData(myPacketHeader, myPacketData, buffer);
send(sockfd, buffer, 18, 0);
...
```

Again, you don't have to use the `header` and `data` structs that I defined. Just use whatever your program needs. The key is that you have a conversion function that writes all of the data, at well-defined offsets, in a well-defined byte order, to a buffer, and that you pass that buffer to the send() function.

On the other side of the network connection, you will need a program to interpret the data it receives. On that side, you need to write the corresponding functions (`ntohHeader`, etc). Those function will `memcpy` the bits out of a buffer and into a local variable, which it can pass to `ntohs` or `ntohl`. I'll leave those functions for you to write.

Comment: Question1: why "d.pf2>>32"? Question2: what is "d.pfd2"?

Comment: Answer2: `d.pfd2` was a typo. Thanks for noticing, I've fixed it. Answer1: Because there is no standard function for converting the byte order of a `uint64_t`, the code converts first the high-order 32 bits followed by the low-order 32 bits.

Answer (score 5):

Well, typically it would look like it's preparing that packet structure into a memory buffer (making judicious calls the the `htonl` family of functions).

If would then use the `send`, `sendto`, `sendmsg` or `write` functions, hopefully with a lot of care taken with the length of the buffer and good error handling/reporting.

(Or one of the Win32 apis for the send, if that is the target plateforms.)

You'll find a good presentation about all this at [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

Specifially for the byte packing part (with endian consideration), look at the [serialization](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#serialization) topic. (There's *way more* detail in that section than what you need for plain fixed-size integer data types.

Comment: I assume the send() method for whatever socket library would then just take the buffer variable as an argument, correct? Can you provide an example of preparing the packet structure into a memory buffer?

Comment: Both links are broken

Comment: @Mat yeah, I found it easily enough, but if I find broken links I tend to leave a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

The code would look different depending on the OS's networking library (*nix uses [Berkeley sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), Windows uses [Winsock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock), etc.).  However, you could create a struct containing all the data you wanted to send in a packet, e.g.,

```
typedef struct
{
    short field1;
    short field2;
    int field3;
} HeaderStruct;

typedef struct
{
    short field1;
    long long field2;
} PacketDataStruct;
```

assuming a 32-bit int size.

**Edit:**

As someone kindly reminded me in the comments, don't forget about converting to and from [Network Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_order). Networking libraries will have functions to assist with this, such as `ntohs`, `nothl`, `htons`, and `htonl`.

Comment: That's along the lines I was thinking. What would sending the packed look like? Can you update the answer with that?

Comment: Make sure you have these structs packed properly, and you deal with any endian-ness issues!

Answer (score 1):

One simple answer is that it would be sent in the format that the receiver expects.  That begs the question a bit, though.  Assuming the data is a fixed size as shown and the receiving end expects, then you could use a packed (1 byte alignment) structure and store the data in each field.  The reason for using 1 byte alignment is that it is typically easier to make sure both ends are expecting the same data.  Without 1 byte alignment, then the structure would possibly look different based on compiler options, 32-bit versus 64-bit architecture, etc.)  And, typically, it is expected that you would send the values in network byte order if the hex values are integers.  You can use functions such as `htons` and `htonl` (and possibly `htobe64` if available) to convert them.

Assuming that the data is in the structure with the desired byte order, then the send call may be something like this:

```
ret = send( socket, &mystruct, sizeof( mystruct ), 0 );
```

That assumes that `mystruct` is declared as an instance of the structure as opposed to a pointer to the structure.

Comment: Now let's say I wanted to send multiple packets like slavik262 showed us. Would I then just have a struct containing sub-structs, and pass THAT to send()?

Comment: @Chad: You can call send() multiple times (note that you should be checking the return code).  If you are using TCP and Nagle's algorithm is being used, then the data would likely all go on the wire as a single packet even though send was called multiple times.  If you are using UDP, though, each send call would result in separate packet.  If that is the case, then you may want to copy it all to a single buffer if you want it to be sent in one packet (which isn't a requirement).

Comment: Doesn't field alignment (and ordering??) vary by compiler and machine? You also have to deal with endianness. That make structs a bad choice unless one is communicating with another instance of the same build of the same program.

Comment: @ikegami:  I discussed that in the answer (htonl, etc.)